# Nightwatch + Cucumber How to describe a generic step

Tags: javascript, cucumber, nightwatch.js

I'm writing some e2e tests using nightwatch and cucumber. I'd like to have a generics steps. Now, my step definition is like this:

```
 When (/^I click on 'Leave a comment'$/, () => {
    return client
    .click('a[id="leave-comment"]')
  });
```

I'd like some like:

```
When (/^I click on  "(.*?)"$/, (text) => {
 ...
});
```

But I can't implement this step using .click. Any idea?

Comment: hi, did you get any success

Comment: not yet, i'm trying something using the answer below + xPath, but i didn't get success :(

Comment: I leave an answer with the solution that I found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution that I found. I needed to define the type of the element and I used xPath

```
When (/^I click on  "(.*?)"$/, (text) => {
 return client
    .useXpath()
    .waitForElementVisible('//button[text()="'+text+'"]', 7000)
    .click('//button[text()="'+text+'"]')
    .useCss()
    .pause(1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't personally use Nightwatch, but have found something that would should work for you.

Look into : [Nightwatch Custom Commands and Assertions](https://github.com/maxgalbu/nightwatch-custom-commands-assertions)

One of the functions it will give you is [jqueryClick](https://github.com/maxgalbu/nightwatch-custom-commands-assertions/blob/master/js/commands/jqueryClick.js), which will give you the ability to do this:

```
When(/^I click on the link with text "(.*?)"$/, (text) => {
    return client.jqueryClick('*:contains('+text+')');
});
```

It adds all of the [jQuery Selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp) to your arsenal, making writing automation just that little bit easier.

Answer (score 0):

Should do the job

```
this.When('I click the "$element" element', (browser, element) => {
     browser.click(element)   
 });
```

If you use page objects you will need to create much more complicated function but this one will work for common `When I click the ".cssClass.ccsClass2" element`